# dhcp not assigning gateway

Tags: debian, dhcp, kvm-virtualization

So I am running a dev server for KVM virtual machines. I have a DHCP server running locally on the host node with the following configuration:

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of integer 8;
option ms-classless-static-routes code 249 = array of integer 8;

subnet xxx.xxx.x.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range xxx.xxx.x.2 xxx.xxx.x.127;
 option routers xxx.xxx.x.1;
 option broadcast-address xxx.xxx.x.255;
 option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
 option netbios-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
 default-lease-time 86400;
 max-lease-time 86400;
 option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 24, xxx, xxx, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, xxx, xxx, x, 1;
 option ms-classless-static-routes 24, xxx, xxx, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, xxx, xxx, x, 1;
         host 102 {hardware ethernet 4A:19:BD:DF:B0:07;fixed-address xxx.xxx.x.5;}


 }
```

/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

```
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server
# installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
#DHCPD_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
#DHCPD_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#       Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#       Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="vmbr0"
```

For reference, this is a debian 7 proxmox server.

The issue is, the server is assigned an IP via DHCP without issue. It gets xxx.xxx.x.5, however the gateway is set as 0.0.0.0 when viewed via route -n and the network therefore is not reachable.

Contents of VM network config file:

```
DEVICE=eth01
BOOTPROTO=dhcp 
ONBOOT=yes
```

[image: invalid argument]

In addition the there is an invalid argument error when it is getting information from DHCP, they might be related.

Error log on client:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried moving the 102 host definition block outside the subnet block?

Comment: no change in the result

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/3j0A0H1m0O1M on the client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difficult to troubleshoot remotely with limited information. But I'd like to try.

First, just a guess. Usually the DEVICE name is `eth0` or `eth1`, not `eth01`. This might explain the "invalid argument error". Make sure you are dealing with the right NIC by `ifconfig -a` or `ip link` in the VM.

Another suspect is the static route. It should have 13 items in the array, instead of your 14. The format is `<netmask>, <network-byte1>, <network-byte2>, <network-byte3>, <router-byte1>, <router-byte2>, <router-byte3>...`. So it should look like this `24,192,168,1,   192,168,1,1,  0,  192,168,1,1`. Take a look [here](https://ercpe.de/blog/pushing-static-routes-with-isc-dhcp-server). I guess the wrong static route overwrites the default gateway.

If that's not the problem, you need a process to debug. From your DHCP config, I assume `vmbr0` is a Linux Bridge and VMs are created from there. You need to confirm the VM network is created right, by checking `virt net-list` and `virt edit <vm>` on the host/hyperviser. You can also use `virt-manager`. Make sure the VM has only one NIC, which is bridged from `vmbr0`.

If still not fixed, go into the VM and debug DHCP client. First, `killall dhclient`, and then run `dhclient eth0` and monitor traffic with `dhcpdump -i eth0` or `tcpdump udp and port 67 or 68`. Look for gateway options. Make sure there's no other DHCP server in the way. (Might be the default NAT from libvirt; or may be another DHCP server from outside, since you have a bridge). You can you can also run `dhcpdump/tcpdump` on the host where you have the DHCP server.

I hope this helps.